# $X$ connected in the order topology $\Rightarrow$ every $A\subset X$ that has an upper bound has a supremum

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, order-theory, solution-verification

I have to prove

> $X$ connected in the order topology (w.r.t. a linear order <) $\Rightarrow$ every $A\subset X$
>   that has an upper bound has a supremum

My attempt:

Reason by contradiction: take $A\subset X$ with an upper bound but no supremum. It follows that $A$ has no maximal element, and that there are infinite increasing sequences $(x_1,x_2,...)$ in $A$, and an infinite sequence $(y_1,y_2,...)$ of upper bounds on $A$. We then consider
$$A_<=\bigcup_{a\in A}\{x\in X|x<a\}$$
$$A_>=\bigcup_{a\text{ an upper bound on $A$}}\{x\in X|a<x\}$$
These are both open in the order topology. It is not hard to verify that these sets partition $X$ and that they are also closed. This way we exhibit $X$ as the union of $2$ separated components, which is a contradiction.$\square$

Since I'm self studying and have no answers of the exercises I just want to verify this answer. I'm most interested in the validity of my reasoning related to the upper-bound stuff (the existence of the infinite sequences and such). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequences aren’t doing anything for you: you never actually use them. It’s the sets $A_<$ and $A_>$ that you want, and with them your argument is fine, though I’d say that it’s a little easier to observe that they are *open* and complementary.

The sequences always exist, but the increasing sequence may not be cofinal in $A$. For example, let $X$ be the [closed long ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29), and let $A$ be the open long ray; then $A$ is unbounded in $X$, but any strictly increasing ordinary sequence in $A$ has a supremum in $A$. Similarly, it’s possible that no decreasing sequence is coinitial in the set of upper bounds (e.g., just turn this example around).

Comment: Sorry I ment a linear order $<$, not just partial. I think it has to be a partition in that case. Also, I realise that I don't really use the sequences, but I'm still curious if I'm correct in that they exist. I wonder because intuitively I thought $A$ is being a set like $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}|x<\pi\}$, but I'm not sure if there's some construction I'm not thinking of that does not require the existence of such sequences.

Comment: @user2520938: You can guarantee that the sequences exist, but you can’t guarantee that that the increasing sequence is cofinal in $A$, or that the decreasing one is coinitial in $A_>$. For that you may need sequences of transfinite length.

Comment: Oke I'll have to think about that. Right now I can't think of a construction in which $<$ is a linear ordering but the increasing sequence is not cofinal, but that's probably because I have very little experience in thinking about orders. But am I correct that with $<$ being a linear order $A_<$ and $A_>$ do partition $X$?

Comment: @user2520938: Yes, and I’m modifying my answer to include an example in which sequences aren’t enough.

Comment: I was thinking that such an example must require some extraordinarily large space, but since this is only my third day doing topology I did not know about the long line yet. Thanks for the answer (x2) and the nice example.

Comment: @user2520938: You’re welcome.